# Can I save my sensitivity as a floating-point number?

Tags: borderlands-2

The in-game slider only goes down to 10, but there are ways to get it lower than that. I've tried Cheat Engine but it's not permanent (as far as I know how to use it). I just spent an hour trying a [hex editing method](https://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/882960797527726404/#c616188473194554202) only to find out it doesn't accept floating point numbers (specifically 2.75).

I figure it's possible because it can apparently be changed to 2.75 via Cheat Engine. I want the best of both worlds. I'd be satisfied with a consistent Cheat Engine table rather than having to find the address each time I start Borderlands 2.

How can I permanently change my in-game mouse sensitivity to 2.75?

Update: Actually Cheat Engine can't change sensitivity to a floating point number. 2.75 autocorrects to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the hex edit method, it's impossible to set the sensitivity to a non-whole number. The game stores the value as a byte, which means it can be a value between 0-255 (Although there's no guarantee the game will accept that full range)

To change this behaviour you would have to mod the game executable itself to use a different type of variable.